# Add binary values with points without shortcut

Tags: java

I have got a school project to add 2 binary numbers in java. The binary numbers can also have decimal values.

`Example - 10.01 + 10.01 = 100.1`

I cannot use short cuts like Integer.parseInt(str,radix); (These projects really suck)... :'(

I just have to use strings and stuff. I tried the following code  but I am getting lost in the mid and especially to overcome the decimal factor is becoming next to impossible for me:-

```
String a = "101";
String b = "101";
for(int i=0;i<a.length() || i<b.length();i++){
    int digit1 = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(a.length()-1));
    int digit2 = Integer.parseInt(b.substring(b.length()-1));
    if(digit1 == 0 && digit2 ==0 && carry == 0) {sum = 0;carry = 0;}
    if(digit1 == 0 && digit2 ==1 && carry == 0) {sum = 1;carry = 0;}
    if(digit1 == 1 && digit2 ==0 && carry == 0) {sum = 1;carry = 0;}
    if(digit1 == 1 && digit2 ==1 && carry == 0) {sum = 0;carry = 1;}
    if(digit1 == 0 && digit2 ==0 && carry == 1) {sum = 1;carry = 0;}
    if(digit1 == 0 && digit2 ==1 && carry == 1) {sum = 0;carry = 1;}
    if(digit1 == 1 && digit2 ==0 && carry == 1) {sum = 0;carry = 1;}
    if(digit1 == 1 && digit2 ==1 && carry == 1) {sum = 1;carry = 1;}
...//could not continue further
```

Please help me...I am stuck very badly. Any help will be gladly appreciated! :)

Comment: What is your actual problem? Just write the 8 possible cases and then keep on adding last digits one by one!

Comment: @Nullpointer I guess the question is clear. Its about binary addition. You can learn about binary addition here -> http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Binary-Numbers

Comment: I know how to add binary numbers..But I am not getting where you are stuck? Why can't you just add digit by digit?

Comment: @Nullpointer I am trying that for the last 1 hour. But getting lost. So I asked for help.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the working code:**

**Note: I have just shown you how to add thses numbers. IF your 1st binary number has (say) 4 digits and 2nd binary number has (say) 10 digits then obviously this code won't work!you have to check that condition and add respective code.I have assumed that both numbers have same digits.**

***Also note the change in for loop conditions!***

```
public class ADDBinary {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String num1 = "1101";
    String num2 = "1010";
    String sum = "";
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num1.length() && i < num2.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println("In for loop");
        char digit1, digit2;
        digit1 = num1.charAt(num1.length() - i - 1);
        digit2 = num2.charAt(num2.length() - i - 1);
        System.out.println("Digits="+digit1+digit2);
        if (digit1 == '0' && digit2 == '0' && carry == 0) {
            sum =  sum + "0";
            carry = 0;
        } else if (digit1 == '0' && digit2 == '1' && carry == 0) {
            sum = sum + "1";
            carry = 0;
        } else if (digit1 == '1' && digit2 == '0' && carry == 0) {
            sum = sum + "1";
            carry = 0;
        } else if (digit1 == '1' && digit2 == '1' && carry == 0) {
            sum = sum + "0";
            carry = 1;
        } else if (digit1 == '0' && digit2 == '0' && carry == 1) {
            sum = sum + "1";
            carry = 0;
        } else if (digit1 == '0' && digit2 == '1' && carry == 1) {
            sum = sum + "0";
            carry = 1;
        } else if (digit1 == '1' && digit2 == '0' && carry == 1) {
            sum = sum + "0";
            carry = 1;
        } else if (digit1 == '1' && digit2 == '1' && carry == 1) {
            sum = sum + "1";
            carry = 1;
        }
    }
    if(carry == 1)
        sum = sum + "1";
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder(sum).reverse().toString());

}
```

}

**I have used same conditions!**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, some tips. 
Looking at your code, I can see eight `if`'s with the same format. This is called code duplication and it is to be avoided. You are basically typing the same lines over and over again, which is more work for you and makes your code less readable, adaptable and maintanable. If you encounter something that needs to be done multiple times, in slightly different ways, make a new method that does that thing.

You say they can have decimal values. That's not really good terminology, decimal implies base10. Radix point is what we call the decimal point in base10, but since we're working with base2, decimal doesn't apply, so we call it radix point instead.

As for your question:
(Deleted this because NullPointer beat me to it.)